# Angular Universal SSG prerenders routes but with empty router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have a very weird issue:

Since i migrated to Standalone Apis with Angular 16, SSR works how it should (with clientHydration()), but when i tried SSG (prerender), everything falls apart, and i cannot get a hold on what's going on because of course, there is 0 error.

files generated got basic index.html content +

```
<router-outlet _ngcontent-ng-c1573660619-0 class="ng-tns-c1573660619-0"></router-outlet><!---->
```

**Very simple question: Does SSG (prerender) still work on Angular Universal coupled with Angular standalone apis ?**

More details =>

```
  import bootstrap from "./src/main.server"

  server.engine(
    "html",
    ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap,
    }),
  )
```

main.server.ts file

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core"

import { environment } from "./environments/environment"
import { bootstrapApplication } from "@angular/platform-browser"
import { AppComponent } from "./app/app.component"
import { serverConfig } from "./app.config.server"

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode()
}

export { AppServerModule } from "./app/app.server.module"
export { renderModule } from "@angular/platform-server"

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, serverConfig)

export default bootstrap
```

AppServerModule file

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core"
import { ServerModule } from "@angular/platform-server"
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component"

@NgModule({
  imports: [ServerModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Comment: usually routes are rendered next to router-outlet, not inside of it. could you check if there is a component rendered nearby?

Comment: Hi thanks @Andrei, thanks for your help: right next to it, i got just <!----> right next to it.

Comment: Updated the question with more details. I believe i put all relevant files, maybe i'm doing something wrong here since migration de angular 16 has been a bit hard for me.

Comment: there were some changes related to hydration in angular 16. that could affect your app. But can not say more without deep debugging

Answer (score 0):

Took me a whole day, but i found my answer.

It was in the way bootstrap function was exported.

this file gave me the answer =>

```
./node_modules/@nguniversal/builders/src/prerender/worker.js
```

it expects a bootstrapping function, which i thought i gave using what people usualy do at the end of **server.ts** file:

```
export * from "./src/main.server"
```

I had in "./src/main.server"

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core"
import { environment } from "./environments/environment"
import { bootstrapApplication } from "@angular/platform-browser"
import { AppComponent } from "./app/app.component"
import { serverConfig } from "./app.config.server"
import { renderApplication } from "@angular/platform-server"

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode()
}

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, serverConfig)

export default bootstrap
```

That looked good enough for me at first, then i had to change it to make prerendering work to:

```
// server.ts
// this part is unchanged 
import bootstrap from "./src/main.server"

// this part is unchanged
server.engine(
  "html",
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap,
  }),
)

// this is what fixed it
export default bootstrap
```

And now everything is OK.